# How can pandas drops some rows in a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to drop some rows in a function. For my general purpose, I would like modify my dataframe like this `df.groupby(['example','columns']).apply(my_function_will_modify_df)`.

I think, basically, my question is regard to pass by reference in python so I made-up an example like this

```
def test(df):
    df.drop(pd.Int64Index([1]))
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(2),'b':range(2)})
data
Out[1]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
```

When I call `test(data)`, my expectation is `data` should be as similar as this

```
data.drop(pd.Int64Index([1])) 
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
```

but it wasn't

I also tried this

```
def test(df):
    p = df.copy()
    p.drop(pd.Int64Index([1]))

test(data)

data
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
```

but nothing happened too.

Could you please help me to change `data` inside function `test(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyword argument `inplace=True` in the drop method:

```
def test(df):
    df.drop(pd.Int64Index([1]), inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks it works if I do it alone. When I used with form `df.groupby(['example','columns']).apply(my_function_will_modify_df)`, it doesn't affect. Do you have this situation?